# "Sharp" (openings, games) in chess: meaning, register, is it related to or different from general usage?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, vocabulary, adjectives, adjective-phrases

It's about *sharp* ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sharp?s=t), [Merriam Learners](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/sharp), [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sharp), [American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=sharp&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)). Only [*Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sharp#Adjective) mentions a *chess* context with the meaning "tactical; risky". On *Chess SE*, the top voted question is about [*very aggressive* [chess] *openings*](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/75/very-aggressive-openings): the person discusses an opening and says it "*makes for a sharp tactical game*" and requests further information about "*very aggressive, tactical, sharp open games*". There are some 14 other instances of the adjective *sharp* being used in the answers and comments throughout that Q&A. One answer discusses another opening and says it's "[*sharp, but sound and deep*](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/360)", seemingly implying it's possible to have a sharp yet *unsound* opening, and if it's unsound to begin with then it that can't be so *keen in intellect* or even that much [*tactical*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tactical?s=t) for that matter. Also if it means *tactical* then why would the person asking say "sharp tactical..."?

The notes about *sharp, keen* and *acute* in the *AHDotEL* are also very interesting:

> Figuratively they indicate mental alertness and clarity of
>   comprehension. *Sharp* suggests quickness and astuteness. [...] *Keen*
>   implies clear-headedness and acuity. [...] *Acute* suggests penetrating
>   perception or discernment.
>
> [ American Heritage Dictionary of the English language, *sharp*. ]

Especially since Merriam-Webster lists as second and third meaning for *sharp* many shades of *keen in* (...intellect, perception, attention, spirit).  *Merriam Learners* is also interesting when they refer to "having or showing a quick ability to notice and understand things" with an example like *sharp questions*, which makes me think that the *product* of a sharp mind may be *sharp* too...

More broadly speaking, there are other phrases/adjectives such as *cutting edge* (technology), *tip of the spear* (?), *state of the art* (device?), *contemporary* (time based), or things like *focused*, *precise*, which I tend to associate one way or another with some of those many meanings *sharp* can have. More typically I'm used to *sharp* being used to mean *clever* or *cunning* to describe someone, especially when they say something *sharp*, and I wasn't really aware this could be informal or that it could be used for  *stylish* (informal) or *expert* (informal).

---

Is there a chess specific usage for *sharp*, what does it mean, is it "tactical; risky", are those just different use cases from books separated by a semicolon; has the word *sharp* become more popular over time, along the lines of *stylish/cool*, or has it replaced [*bright*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bright?s=t) for *quick-witted/intelligent* (Dictionary.com) in modern casual English *i.e.* is the chess usage adapted from general usage, or different from it; when it modifies other adjectives and qualifies inanimate things and abstractions, or figuratively, is *sharp* just an intensifier, like the adverb "very", or do you pick up the nuances from context so that you feel it's one of *aggressive, complex, modern, vetted by pros, popular*, or *stylish*, depending: which one was it in the chess question (*sharp tactical game/very aggressive sharp open games*)?

Comment: Okay,  did you ask this question  or at least a manageable version of it  on SE: Chess? Wouldn't "they" know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharp is an adjective. It has a particular meaning in chess, and you would need to be a chess player to fully appreciate its meaning (I'm not). Its meaning is hinted at by the use in the forum. A sharp game means that the player needs to think deeply about move sequences, and characterised by lots of exchanges of pieces, contrasted with a game in which a player is able to use patterns of pieces to choose the best move, and the position becomes blocked. The meaning is apparently an extended from the usual meanings of "Exact, sudden, cutting". ("Exact" because any error would lead to a big loss, "sudden" because there might be sudden large exchanges of pieces, "cutting" because of the large loss of pieces on both sides.)

An opening may be sharp and unsound (aggressive, but a bad move, for example, bringing the queen out too early). It can also be both sharp and sound.

As for register, would be "technical" or "jargon". This use is  not part of most people's vocabulary. You can't generalise to use outside of chess. You can't use sharp to mean "aggressive or risky" when talking about a business plan, for example.

As you note from the dictionary, sharp has a large number of secondary meanings. The chess meaning hasn't made it into the other dictionaries, yet the forums show that it has currency in the chess sub-culture.

Comment: Thank you! It seems I didn't pay enough attention to the Chess site as someone actually had already asked and I think you'll find the [answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/16176) interesting. In the case of a position, it's like at every move one can fall on their sword and you're living on the edge, it's like aggressively intellectual and unforgiving or something like that. The answer provides _calm_ as some kind of antonym, so to speak. I'm curious as to when that sort of usage started etc. There's reference to a [glossary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_chess#S)... which, in

Comment: turn refers most likely to [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=3jFlCQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA221&vq=sharp&dq=Kaan%202016%20chess&pg=PA244#v=snippet&q=sharp&f=false) from the Kaan 2016 footnote...there's direct reference to _double-edged_ there. Anyways, I'm also curious about how that plays out in [French](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/27764/3177) if that's any interest to you. Thanks for your help with this. I still find it interesting from a language point of view. Cheers! cc @Clare